# Нужна помощь в решении задачи С++

Tags: c++, математика, циклы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу реализовать цикл факториала(суть работы заключается в том,что бы решить пример, использую только цикл for, (никак иначе!!!))
N вводить с клавиатуры!
Вот что у меня есть сейчас:

```
        #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    float s=0,p;
    int i,j,n;
    cin >> n;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        p=1;
        for(j=1;j<i;i++){
            p=p*(factorial(i)/factorial(j)) /*вот тут не смог разобраться,
 по этому обозначил так, жду помощи */
        s+=p
        }
    cout << s << endl;
    system("pause");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не пойму - вам это нужно? Функция факториала?

```
long long factorial(int j)
{
    long long f = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= j; ++i) f*=i;
    return f;
}
```

Или

```
for(j=1;j<i;i++)
{
    long long fi = 1, fj = 1;
    for(int k = 1; k <= i; ++k) fi*=k;
    for(int k = 1; k <= j; ++k) fj*=k;
    p=p*fi/fj;
```

Только я бы немного на бумажке посчитал :) - там очень многое сокращается! Рекомендую не считать два факториала и делить, а расписать их - получится для `i!/j!` что-то вроде

```
    long long f = 1;
    for(int k = j+1; k <= i; ++k) f*=k;
```

Comment: Неа, нельзя создавать новую функцию, нужно это реализовать с помощью цикла for

Comment: См. дополненный ответ